# How to fetch fibonacci series of 1 to 100 using Java Streams and add it into a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, fibonacci

I can write this code using Normal approach. But using Streams i tried like this but limit doesn't work here for that range and IntStream.range() method i'm not able to use here.

```
Stream.iterate(new int[]{0,1}, f -> new int[]{f[1], f[0]+f[1]})
        .limit(10)
        .map(n -> n[0])
        .forEach(System.out::println);
        //.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please reply.

Comment: What do you mean by *limit does not work*?

Comment: limit is giving only 10 characters as we have defined limit(10).. we can define limit(100) and all. but my requirement is to fetch those fibonacci numbers which are in between 1 to 100. So here how could we use limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any version of Java newer than 8, then `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Stream
                //Generate a stream of arrays like this {0,1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}...etc.
                .iterate(new int[] { 0, 1 }, f -> new int[] { f[1], f[0] + f[1] })
                //Keep only the 1st element of each array.
                .map(n -> n[0])
                //Drop only 0.
                .dropWhile(i -> i < 1)
                //Take any number which is <= 100.
                .takeWhile(i -> i <= 100)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Of course, `dropWhile` can be avoided by using `{ 1, 2 }` as seed.

Java 8 doesn't offer a predicate-based way of limiting/stopping the stream, so I'd stick to a loop on that version.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I've been reading a lot of good answers here, the javadocs of `java.util.stream` package and classes, and playing with them frequently. But I don't know much, just learning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added comments to make it easier and faster to understand for newbies like me. Hoping you could accept the comments.

Comment: Does dropWhile(i -> i < 1) run only for the first number 0 or does it run for every number ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 It is evaluated until its predicate returns false.